# Burley trailer hitch, classic or alternative?

Tags: trailer

I've just bought a new bike that I intend to tow my Burley trailer. I've always used a standard hitch before but this will not fit on this bike because of the way the rear drop out is made.

I gather my options are the alternative hitch and the classic hitch.

The alternative hitch looks ideal.  However, I can't appear to get hold of one in the UK.  It looks like it might be discontinued.  Does anyone know if that is the case?

As for the classic hitch, I'm reasonably convinced that it will fit. However, I'm unsure how quick and easy it will be to disconnect and connect the trailer. My daily routine, storage space etc. means that I need to do this once a day.  So my question concerning the classic hitch is, how long does it take to remove and reconnect the trailer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the "Classic" system where the end of the towing arm from the trailer had a moulded plastic part that fit in the angle between the seat stay and chain stay tubes. It then had a hinged part that was tightened down onto the seat stay.

It only took 30 seconds to fit or remove.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete list of Burley spares:

http://www.extrauk.co.uk/downloads/8c7cd0bd823a312e718625ce27335ef7421e6b72/2010_Burley_Spares

Here is the the UK distributor:

http://www.extrauk.co.uk/product/list/Burley/Trailer_Spares/

Get in touch with them asking if they have the part available. Or ask your bike shop if they 'deal with Extra' and ask them to phone up for you to see if part x-y-z is available.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

> [A standard hitch] will not fit on this bike because of the way the rear drop out is made.

If your dropout has hoods that interfere with the hitch, you can get [an adapter from Burley](https://burley.com/collections/hitch-adapter/products/hitch-adapter) to extend the quick release beyond the hoods. There are also adapters for various thru-axles or [special thru-axles with an integrated extension](https://burley.com/collections/hitch-adapter/products/thru-axle).